# Something wicked happened resolving 'apt.wxwidgets.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

Tags: apt, software-sources, wxpython

When running `sudo apt-get update` I get several errors like this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.wxwidgets.org/dists/lucid-wx/Release.gpg
Something wicked happened resolving 'apt.wxwidgets.org:http' (-5 - No
address associated with hostname)
```

It seems that apt.wxwidgets.org is down. Is it temporary or is it permanently moved/gone?

Answer (score 2):

The downloads page of [wxwidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/) now links to [the CodeLite website](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets30Binaries#toc2) for Debian/Ubuntu packages. It seems the original repository is now defunct.

The new repository has packages for a number of versions of Ubuntu even though the instructions only mention 13.10, 14.04 and 14.10.

To add the repository, first import the key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
```

Then add the source:

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wxwidgets.list <<EOF
deb http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu/   $(lsb_release -sc) universe
EOF
sudo apt-get update
```